# Не могу установить pyaudio на python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

Пробовал по разному. Через pipwin пишет:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xcf' in file C:\Users\Пингвин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pipwin-script.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

В способе с .whl, я перешел в папку с файлом и:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

, что выводит:

> ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: python точно 64битный стоит?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Пингвин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pipwin-script.py
```

похожая ересь была, только с `pyautogui`, из-за того, что путь скачивания имеет кириллицу (русские буквы) — оно выдает ошибку.

я просто переустановил всю программу для питона, чтобы она не доходила до папки с кириллицей.
может, у вас также сработает.